# Is a function that has finite side limits monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which has finite side limits at any real point. Is this function monotonic? I know that the converse is true, but I wonder if this also holds.

Comment: Try with $x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\sin(x)$ and you'll have your answer :)